# Do transmitters create magnetic fields and radiation?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electrical-engineering, antennas

In the company I work for (I am a software engineer) we develop a system which uses a transmitter (antenna) that creates a magnetic field. I also know that radio station transmitters create radio waves, so I am somewhat confused.

Do the coils built into the transmitter create an EM radiation when a current passes through them or do they create a magnetic field? Maybe both?

I have very limited knowledge of physics, so I would appreciate an intuitive rather than a formal type of answer.

Answer (score 2):

Every change in a magnetic field automatically creates an electric field and vice versa. For technical purposes, however, magnetic antennas create a stronger magnetic near field (i.e the field that can be measured less than a wavelength away from the antenna), while "electrical" antennas create a stronger electric near field. So depending on application, engineers will favor one type over the other.

Independently of the type of antenna, magnetic or electric, the far field (i.e. more than a couple of wavelengths away from the antenna), the energy density in both the magnetic and the electric field components will be the same.

Having said that, some or many of the coils in your transmitter may not be meant to be antennas to begin with. In modern power transmitters they are more likely power combiners and matching elements.

Comment: You didn't mention radiation in your reply. Would it be correct to say that antenna that produces magnetic field also produces electromagnetic radiation, or for the latter you need a different kind of antenna?

Comment: By the usual definition of "antenna", yes, however, many magnetic antennas are explicitly designed to produce a strong near field, but as little far field (which is probably what you mean by "radiation") as possible. This is the case for e.g. inductive heating systems, wireless power transmitters etc.. The technical use of these antennas is limited entirely to their near field.

Comment: I understand. So basically EM radiation such as light, radio or xray are the continuation of a magnetic field (far field)?

Comment: Yes, far away from the antenna the energy is equally divided in magnetic and electric field components of electromagnetic waves and then the antenna (or emitter) type does not matter. What matters is only the frequency and the amplitude of these waves.

Comment: @user3251930 It might help to know that the full glory of Maxwell's equations can be a pain except in fairly simple configurations, so people have sussed out some useful approximation regimes. The "far field" and "near field" in particular take on relatively simple expressions, and it is those (locally dominate) components of the complete solution to which CuriousOne refers. It's all "radiation" at some level, however.

Answer (score 0):

The coil controls the fluctuation of the current and thus the fluctuation of the magnetic field around the transmitter. The antenna in that arrangement, I assume an electric dipole or monopole, is a kind of a capacitor and its role is to change the ratio of the electric to magnetic field before it is to hit free space, it is a matching transformer to the impedance of ether $120\pi = 377[\Omega]$. The combination of the coil with the capacitor is a resonator at which radiation is possible with that particular $E$ to $H$ ratio. (If the antenna is a loopy kind then itself is inductive, and instead of a coil the matching is done with an external capacitor controlling the electric field fluctuation.)